# Run function on React.Intl <FormattedMessage>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-intl

I am trying to run a function to do further string manipulation on the result of the FormattedMessage. I cannot find a way even after running it through a function as below :

```
<Button text={ this.testMethod(buttonText) } />

testMethod(result){
 return result;
}
```

In summary: I am trying to get the actual text and not the object and then do some string manipulation.

Don't want this:
{id: "test", defaultMessage: "Hello there"}

Need: To access "Hello there" and for example extract the word "there"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Add a component as a child of `FormattedMessage` to do further transformation. Here is a minimal snippet to get you started with

```
<FormattedMessage id="hello">
  {(text) => {
    console.log(text);
    return <>{text.toUpperCase()}</>;
  }}
</FormattedMessage>
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit React-intl FormattedMessage Callback]